# How to create resizable ToolBar (or ActionBar) in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm developing an app which shows user profile similar to WhatsApp Contact profile  (Option->view Contact). it has resizable ToolBar (or ActionBar) like this.
[image: Option -> View Contact]

There's library called **No boring ActionBar** available **[here](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar)** but, it's not gives solid color to `ActionBar` at the end (maximum collapse) like WhatsApp does.
I want to know that how can I achieve this into my app. Any suggestions will be welcome. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatsapp used the normal AppCompat Toolbar and implemented the Material Transitions.

Comment: can you give me link about any example or libraries so, I can refer it. Thank you

Comment: I've used
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: and http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/ for the overall Toolbar & Transitions and http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html for the height of the Toolbar

Comment: Thanks a lot man! this will help me alot